# Hibernate eclipse tool for Pojo class generation?

Tags: java, hibernate

As i am using Hibernate tool for eclipse to generate Java classes for each table of database.

i saw one issue let us suppose we have table **A** and i generated pojo class **A.java** .
A.java class also content named query inside Java class now suppose i deleted/added some column from table **A** and now if i will again generate pojo class I have to manually copy-paste those query into Pojo can we put those query in some common place and use them?

Here is the link How Pojo can be generated